# Can i minimize my function with this two post sends, i have problem with connecting with server

Tags: web

```
            let location = $('input[name="searchBoxl"]').val();
            let type = document.getElementById("types").value;
```

#Opcioni problem

```
                $.post({
                    url: "rest/login?username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(odgovor) {}
```

#I ovde je post method

#Ovaj deo je DAO

```
private void writePromoCode(String putanja, PromoCode code) throws IOException {
    putanja += "\\data\\Codes.csv";
    Writer upis = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(putanja, true));
    upis.append(code.getId());
    upis.append(",");
    upis.append(code.getCode());
    upis.append(",");
    upis.append(code.getUses().toString());
    upis.append(",");
    upis.append(code.getExpiraton());
    upis.append(",");
    upis.append(code.getDiscount().toString());
    upis.append("\n");
    upis.flush();
    upis.close();
}
```

#Ovde se opet javlja greska

#I ovde

Comment: BufferedReader citac = null;
  String putanja = path + "\\data\\Codes.csv";
  try {
   File fajl = new File(putanja);
   citac = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fajl));
   String linija = "";
   while((linija = citac.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parametri = linija.split(",");
    String id = parametri[0];
    String code = parametri[1];
    Integer uses = Integer.parseInt(parametri[2]);
    String expiration = parametri[3];
    Double discount = Double.parseDouble(parametri[4]);
    PromoCode pc = new PromoCode(id,code,uses,expiration,discount);
    codes.put(id, pc);

Comment: const url = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var id = url.get('name');